# How to install Content Porter 2013 SP1 to Tridion 2013 SP1

Tags: 2013, installation, content-porter

I'm trying to install SDL Content Porter 2013 SP1 to interact with SDL Tridion 2013 SP1.

Tridion manual says only content porter client software is required, and there is no need to install anything on TCM server on 2013 SP1("Installing Content Porter overview" section of the manual).

But I cannot install client software, because "Content Porter" menu doesn't appear  on Tridion 2013 SP1's ribbon tools tab,

How can I install Content Porter 2013 SP1 client?

Or do I have to install Content Porter Server software?

Regard,

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Technically the message is right - there is no Content Porter Server installer anymore, this is now included in the standard Content Manager Core.

But the client installer is not included in the CM Core (long story short: we couldn't finish the client in time for the 2013 SP1 release).

So you still need to run an installer (you can get it from Customer Support) on the server, which will install the Content Porter Client Click-Once installer in Tridion. After running this (and refreshing your browser) you'll see the Content Porter icon in the Tools tab.

Comment: Just for clarification, the installer that Nuno refers to here is just the `Install SDL Tridion Content Porter 2013 SP1` installer file that is in the root of the `Content Porter 2013 SP1.zip` folder (available on the client/partner FTP site). Running this on the Tridion 2013 SP1 server added the `Content Porter` icon to the 'Tools' tab (after clearing the browser cache).

Answer (score 4):

Note also that you will not need a Content Porter license when running Content Porter 2013 SP1 on a Tridion 2013 SP1 system.