# How to use Content Porter on SDL Web 8?

Tags: web8, content-porter

I want to use Content Porter on SDL Web8.

Documentation describes that no server side installation is required to use Content Porter, and client installation is available from "Tools" tab of Content Manager Explorer.

[Manual(Live Content)](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/web/pub.xql?action=home&pub=SDL%20Web%20Content%20Porter-v1&lang=en-US#docid=GUID-A51F260E-A802-4829-A3E1-42863BC5E20E&addHistory=true&query=&scope=&tid=&filename=GUID-A51F260E-A802-4829-A3E1-42863BC5E20E.xml&resource=&inner_id=&toc=false&eventType=lcContent.loadDocGUID-A51F260E-A802-4829-A3E1-42863BC5E20E)

But there is not Content Porter icon on "Tools" tab. So I installed Content Porter to CM Server, then Content Porter icon appeared on "Tools" tab, but it's not clickable. I used Internet Explorer.

[image]

Is any installation required to use Content Porter?

How can I install Content Porter.

Regards,

Comment: This happens sometimes (also in 2013 SP1). You'll need to reload the Content Manager explorer UI for the icon to show, seems to be cache related. Either F5 or restart your browser, and you should be good to go.

Comment: Did you get a chance to look into this post? this has some useful tips on the content porter. 
http://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/5760/how-to-install-content-porter-2013-sp1-to-tridion-2013-sp1

Comment: Please also see my answer from here: http://tridion.stackexchange.com/a/8553/71

Comment: Check in Internet Explorer.

Comment: I experienced same issue, deleting the browser history in IE resolved the issue!!

Comment: I installed "Web Content Porter 8" into CM server on another environment, and it's no problem at this time. I'm not sure what was problem.