# SDL Web8 CME - Not able to see content porter add on available under tools in CME UI

Tags: cme, web8

Is the Content Porter not released in SDL Web8 cms ? What are the options to migrate the content (components, pages, CT, PT etc) from Dev-CMS to QA-CMS Environment if content porter is not available in SDL Web8.

Comment: Did you already try clearing cache and refreshing as per http://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/15147/how-to-use-content-porter-on-sdl-web-8 ?

Answer (score 5):

Check your installation Media for Web 8. You should have this:

[image]

Run the intaller, then look for the icon the CME Tools section.  Click it to install the client.

If you have downloaded and ran CP 8 before and if the icon just does not appear in the CME, clear the browser cache then refresh and look for it again.